# Android Send/Receive UDP every 5 sec

Tags: android, udp

This is my first post at the stackoverflow...
I am dealing with android app few weeks ago so my Knoledge is limited.

I want to send and receive UDP pakets enery 5 secs.I found example code BUT it use a button for that.

### That is the code:

class Client implements Runnable
    {
        public Client()
        {
        }

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            String outMessage = txtOutMessage.getText().toString();
            String outIp = txtOutIp.getText().toString();
            int outPort = Integer.parseInt(txtOutPort.getText().toString());

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(outIp);
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            byte[] buf = outMessage.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, serverAddr, outPort);
            socket.send(packet);

            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            socket.receive(receivePacket);
            final String recvMsg = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txtInMessage.setText(recvMsg);
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please advice 
Thanks in advanced
Nikos

Comment: So you have code that sends a single UDP packet.  What mechanism can you use to do something 5 seconds from now, repeatedly? How can you combine them?  Think like a programmer here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using a thread? Something like this would work:

```
//create a thread
Thread t = new Thread()

{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
            {
            try
                {
                //do your stuff
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                //thread to sleep for 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)

                } catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    ie.printStackTrace(); //catch the exception for thread.sleep
                }   
            }
        }
    };
t.start(); //start the thread
```

I have something very similar but mine checks for incoming data ever 100 milliseconds and checks for outgoing data every 250 milliseconds, I have one thread for each of those, I then have a separate thread which runs every 20 seconds to check the socket to make sure its alive and to do some socket validation, and to create a new socket if its failed.